# The following _TypeError was thrown building ScopedModelDescendant<ProductsModel>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedModel<ProductsModel>]):

Tags: flutter, integer

Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════ The following _TypeError was thrown building ScopedModelDescendant(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedModel]): type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Product'

```
int  _selectedProductIndex;
```

I cant declare => int  _selectedProductIndex;
The problem int not a subtype can fix with `var` keywords.
Why please tell me ?

````
    // Error gone here :)
    // But need to dive ..

    return _selectedProductIndex; 
    
   //If i uncomment this underline :: Error happened
    //return _products[_selectedProductIndex]; //Error happened here 
  }```
````

Comment: Can you add full code of your method?

Comment: I guess you've declared a method return an integer not a product.

Comment: [link]http://tenmileshotel.com/users/Screenshot%20from%202021-11-19%2007-45-13.png

Comment: I uploaded on mine server with SS bro

Comment: [link]https://tenmileshotel.com/users/Screenshot%20from%202021-11-19%2007-45-02.png

Comment: The error happened here.

Comment: ```int _selectedProductIndex;      //Fixed if we changed from var => int ?```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
   print(test());
}

test() {
   Int? _selectedProductIndex;
   return _selectedProductIndex;
}
```

Output : null

Or

Edit : can you try to change

```
Product<int>
```

Comment: yea bro...But i added int ? _selectedProductIndex;
```int get selectedProductIndex{
    return _selectedProductIndex;
  }

  Product get selectedProduct {
    // Error gone here :)
    // But need to dive ..
    //return _selectedProductIndex;
    //If i uncomment underline :: Error happened
    return _products[_selectedProductIndex];
  }```  gonna Error

Comment: [link]http://tenmileshotel.com/users/Screenshot%20from%202021-11-19%2009-26-30.png

Comment: Can you ss error line i cant 1 more line error

Comment: return _selectedProduct!.toInt();

Comment: Hey can you add full code product.dart so we can easily see your problem

Comment: product.dart
```import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Product {
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price; 
  final String image;
  final bool isFavourite;
  
  Product(
    {required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price, 
    required this.image,
    this.isFavourite = false}
  );
}```

Comment: Full code here. thanks
[link]https://pastebin.com/MD7LRsR1

Comment: models/product.dart 
[link]https://pastebin.com/R57UTDmE

Comment: Ss with ui error not gone when i add 
=>  ```int? _selectedProductIndex; ```
[link]http://tenmileshotel.com/users/Screenshot%20from%202021-11-19%2011-14-43.png

also   ```int get selectedProductIndex{
    return _selectedProductIndex!.toInt();
  }```

Comment: Pleae check in mine SS. i changed int ? from var .
Also removed !.toInt().
Error gone. but i dont want like this. Please check in SS [link]http://tenmileshotel.com/users/Screenshot%20from%202021-11-19%2011-22-09.png

Comment: When i return like this, =>  return _selectedProductIndex!.toInt();  //Error happened
[link]http://tenmileshotel.com/users/Screenshot%20from%202021-11-19%2011-26-04.png

Comment: wait i need to try

Comment: hey check this `return _products[_selectedProductIndex?.toInt()?? 0];`

Comment: my battery low sorry if im late to reply

Comment: thanks bro Im waiting yr reply :)

Comment: ```return _products[_selectedProductIndex?.toInt()?? 0];```  Already check but Range Error. shown in ui. Valid value range is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
var  _selectedProductIndex;
```

Use this

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 